# Connect to a MySQL database and count the number of rows

Tags: mysql, database, count, rows

I need to connect to a MySQL database and then show the number of rows. This is what I've got so far;

```
    <?php

include "connect.php";


db_connect(); 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hacker"); 
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); 


echo $num_rows; 

?>
```

When I use that code I end up with this error;

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\Documents and Settings\username\Desktop\xammp\htdocs\news2\results.php on line 10
```

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: You are probably experiencing an error on the server side, this would leave $result as an invalid mysql result resource.

Comment: kasperjj is right, your syntax is OK... what's in connect.php? are you sure mysql credentials are correct?

Answer (score 5):

You would probably be better of asking the database to aggregate the number of rows instead of transferring them all to php and doing the counting there.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hacker
```

Comment: would be more efficient, but his php warning is an clear indicator of a former error

Answer (score 2):

take a habit to run all queries this way:

```
$sql   = "SELECT * FROM hacker";
$res   = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$sql);
```

and you will always have comprehensive error information
and take appropriate corrections

also, as it was mentioned above, the only reliable way to count rows is `SELECT count(*)` query

```
$sql   = "SELECT count(*) FROM hacker";
$res   = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$sql);
$row   = mysql_fetch_row($res);
$count = $row[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

change your code as following:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hacker");
echo mysql_error();
```

You have an SQL-Error or your not connected to the database